# Does seqistatd command calculate the standard error of time spent in each state?

Tags: r, traminer

I'm using the R packages TraMineR to compute and analyze the event state sequences. My alphabet consists of 7 states. 
I used the `seqistatd` command to calculare the mean time spent in each state for a number of subpopulation I'm interest in (for example women with different educational level).
However, I would like to add the information about the standard error or the standard deviation of the mean time spent in each state. Is it possible to do that within the `seqistatd` line command or do I have to compute somehow the estimation on my own?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the function `seqistatd` does return the time in each state for each individual sequence. It is easy however to compute the mean time and variance by groups with the `apply` function. I illustrate below with an example using the `biofam`data provided by `TraMineR`.

```
library(TraMineR)
data(biofam)
bf.seq <- seqdef(biofam[,10:25])

bf.ldist <- seqistatd(bf.seq)
sel <- (biofam$sex == "man")

## Mean and variance of time in each state for men
(meant <- apply(bf.ldist[sel,], 2, mean, na.rm=TRUE))
(vart <- apply(bf.ldist[sel,], 2, var, na.rm=TRUE))
## and for women
(meant <- apply(bf.ldist[!sel,], 2, mean, na.rm=TRUE))
(vart <- apply(bf.ldist[!sel,], 2, var, na.rm=TRUE))
```